# Provide data from xml file via REST on tomcat server start

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I am currently trying to implement a Java application to get some config data for another application. The java app has to read in several parameters from some kind of `configuration.xml` file. After the values are fetched, the data should be accessible through a REST call. Since the data is pretty crucial for other applications, the method which loads the data from the `config.xml` should run immediately after the start of the tomcat to store the value in the app and make it accessible for later REST calls

Here is my planned sequence of events:

- launch app/service/class on tomcat start
- read data from the `.xml` file
- process the data for a REST call
- set up a REST service to access the data

**What will be a reasonable way to implement the problem?**

I hope you guys can give me some hints or some basic construction.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve by saying `the method should run immediately after the start of the tomcat` - when you call the REST api, it will be available.  Or is this a very slow process?

Comment: @ScaryWombat There are just 5-10 parameters in the `config.xml` file so I guess it won´t be too time consuming to read the data.

Comment: Great, just do it then.

Comment: @ScaryWombat So you are saying a "normal" REST service will be enough to do the job?

Comment: Just use a plain HTTP server to make this file accessible.